# Social media data returns blank output

Tags: social-media

I have mathematica 10.3
The `SocialMediaData` command, asks me for for an access key. When I paste it, it returns a blank network. The related commands also return blank lists `{}`.

I work on linux (ubuntu and archlinux with both awesome and gnome environment). One year ago I had used older versions of Mathematica and these commands worked fine. Did anyone encountered similar problem?

Thanks.

The code I use is:

```
SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"].
```

Comment: Please add the code to reproduce this. Otherwise this question most likely  cannot be answered in a useful way.

Comment: The same emptiness in my case. After the upper command I am asked for teh "SocialMediaData Authetication" to copy and paste, but the result is an empty plot wihout any error ... as far as I remember it worked in prior versions (10.0-10.2)

Comment: Same for me. And the code you (Yves) ask for is just the one line in the original post

Comment: Me too. Mathematica Home 10.3 Windows 10 pro x64

Answer (score 8):

**This is not a bug in Mathematica.**  Facebook has changed what information can be retrieved through their API.  It is no longer possible to retrieve the information necessary to build your friend network unless your friends have also explicitly authorized Wolfram to access their data.

When I run `SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"]` I get a network with only three nodes.  These three nodes are the friends who have themselves used Mathematica's `SocialMediaData`, and have thus already authorized Wolfram to access their data.

Reference:

http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/14/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/

Unfortunately, since May 2015, it is not possible to programmatically retrieve one's Facebook friend network, either through Mathematica or any other tool that uses official Facebook APIs.

Answer (score 6):

> Mr. Davis,
>
> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> It does appear that the SocialMediaData functionality it not currently >behaving properly for the social networks mentioned in the documentation. I >have filed a report with our developers so that they may look into the issue.
>
> We are always interested in improving Mathematica, and I want to thank you >once again for bringing this issue to our attention.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Kyle Martin
> Wolfram Technology Group
> Wolfram Research, Inc.
> support@wolfram.com
> http://support.wolfram.com

Comment: People at Wolfram support should have known about [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/14/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/).